# AngularJS: Under what specific circumstances is a promise returned by $http rejected?

Tags: angularjs, http, promise

I'm pretty new to Angular (or JavaScript in general) and I have a dumb question here. I understand how promises work, but under what specific circumstances will a promise returned by a `$http` request (`PUT` or `GET` or whatever) be rejected? I'm pretty sure that if a request times out then the promise will definitely be rejected; but what about other errors like 404 or 403? I couldn't find any such information from Angular Docs... Thanks a lot!

Comment: This errors will pass throught Interceptors, and you can handle this by yourself: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Any response status that is not in the 200 <= n < 300 range is considered a failed request. See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L235

Answer (score 1):

If somehow any $http error occur, the promise will be rejected. The $httpProvider is based on the [Interceptor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern), where every request/response pass through a pipeline that handles this error.

The default Interceptor, built in the AngularJS will do something like this, to reject the promise:

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
  // do something on error
  if (canRecover(rejection)) {
    return responseOrNewPromise
  }
  return $q.reject(rejection); //<------ Rejecting the Promise here given a http error
}
```

You can build and attach your own Interceptor inside the $httpProvider to handle specific errors (400, 500, etc). Take a look at the [Interceptor](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$http) section, under the $http documentation.